# not able to get array in the correct shape

Tags: php

I am trying to create an elasticsearch query and for that I need to get my array in a particular shape but I am not able to get it.

desired output

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [
                    "match": {
                        "active": 1
                    },
                    "bool": {
                        "should": [
                            {
                                "match": {
                                    "workspace_type.keyword": "lounge"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "match": {
                                    "workspace_type.keyword": " cafe"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My source code

```
$query = [
        'query' => [
            'bool' => [
                'must' => [
                    'bool' => [
                        'must' => []
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];

    $active_query = [
        'match' => [
            "active" => 1
        ]
    ];

    $query['query']['bool']['must']['bool']['must'][] = $active_query;

    $workspace_type_query = [
        'match' => [
            "workspace_type.keyword" => "lounge"
        ]
    ];
    $workspace_type_object = (object) $workspace_type_query;

    $query['query']['bool']['must']['bool']['must']['bool']['should'][] = $workspace_type_object;
```

only issue with this is I am not able to get must[] (the one above match and active ) and it was either coming as an indexed object like

```
{
"0": {
   "match": {
       "active": 1
    }
  }
}
```

or just an object like this

```
{
   "match": {
      "active": 1
    }
}
```

but both these cases are not acceptable for the elasticsearch query that I am trying to generate .. any assistance would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the extra index that you create for `must` is wrong.

When you change it to

```php
$query['query']['bool']['must']['bool']['must'] = $active_query;
```

it seems to work.

The result is

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "bool": {
          "must": {
            "match": {
              "active": 1
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: But I need it that way to be able to get the correct results from Elasticsearch .. Basically it should be active and it can be either of a few items but at least one of them

Comment: Ah, you need to transform the json output coming _from_ ES to the one above? Sorry but I dont get it. You create the json in PHP and send it to ES?

Comment: Yes I create it in PHP and then need to send it to ES .. Its a laravel project and I am using a package called scout-Elasticsearch-Laravel

Comment: So the package create `must[]` (array) but you need `must{}` (object)? Did i get that right?

Comment: I want must[] and I am getting must{}